# Complexity of non-recursiveDFS code

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, depth-first-search

I think the complexity of this code is:
Time : O (v) : v is the vertex
Space: O (v) : v is the vertex

```
public void dfs() {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();
        stack.add(source);

        while (!stack.empty()) {
            int vertex = stack.pop();
            System.out.println(" print v: " + vertex);
            for (int v : graph.adj(vertex)) {
                if (!visited[v]) {
                    visited[v] = true;
                    stack.add(v);
                    edgeTo[v] = vertex;
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) answers it, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `graph.adj()` always produce a bounded number of vertices (maybe just one), then you are right.

However, if it depends in any way on the total number of vertices present in the system, then it is not.  If this dependency is linear, then the algorithm is O(n^2).

Generalizing, if f(n) is the average number of `graph.adj()` per vertex, then the answer is O(n*f(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You are traversing the adjacency matrix of each unvisited node, and each node is visited exactly once. Thus, you are in effect visiting each edge once, and thus the complexity is `O(E)`, which can be as much as `O(v^2)` in worst case.